# Errors "Page expired" when upload project Laravel to Shared hosting(Cpanel)

Tags: php, laravel, hosting

I have a problem when Upload project Laravel to shared hostting.
Everything is ok when i test by Xampp(Localhost). But at the hosting, I click "Submit button" on every Form-> It apprear: Page Expied
(The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again).
Although i have Csrf_token and search many questions about my problem, i cannot resloved it.
Please help me!!!
This is my form:

```
<form action="lienhe" method="POST" role="lienhe">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}"/>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Tên bạn</label>
    <textarea style="height: 28px" name="name_lienhe" autofocus></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Nội dung liên hệ / phản hồi </label>
     <textarea style="height: 192px" name="noidung_lienhe"></textarea>
    </div>
</form>
```

In web.php:

```
Route::get('lienhe','LoginUserController@getLienHe');
Route::post('lienhe','LoginUserController@postLienHe');
```

Please check in myweb:  http://traodo.com for more information.
Thank a lot.

Comment: Please help me. I'm waiting...

Comment: Clear your browser cache or open your website in incog mode. I cannot understand the site language but tried to register and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Thank you. But it don't work.

Answer (score 0):

In your project, in config folder there is file called **session.php**. Check if your session driver is file.

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
```

if you have thet the check session storage path from below variable and make sure it is writable.[Or check folder permission on server]

```
'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. I made it but nothing happen. I don't know how to make it now.

Comment: what is file permission for framework/sessions folder?

Comment: Permission is : 0755. is it ok?

Comment: Yes it should be